AWS SSL Certificate for www stuck 'Pending validation'
I registered two AWS S3 buckets: shufflemcq.com and www.shufflemcq.com. I pointed shufflemcq.com to www.shufflemcq.com
I transferred my shufflemcq.com domain name to Route 53 and created a shufflemcq.com hosted zone there.
I created a Cloudfront distribution, using the www.shufflemcq.com bucket as the origin domain.
Then I tried adding shufflemcq.com, www.shufflemcq.com, and *.shufflemcq.com as "Alternate domain name (CNAME)." That required me to request a Custom SSL certificate, which I did. For shufflemcq.com and *.shufflemcq.com certificate status immediately showed up as 'Success.' But for www.shufflemcq.com it's stuck as 'Pending validation.'
I tried to manually add the SSL certificate CNAME name and value to the Route 53 hosted zone - but that didn't do anything.
How should I proceed?
